# Обработка клиента если вдруг упал сервер на андроиде

Tags: java, android, сервер, сокет

Мой сервер на ***андроиде***, может пропасть wifi по которому идут данные.

**Сервер только читает строку!**

На сокетах.

Если вдруг у меня упадет сервер, как мне оповестить клиента, что больше не нужно ничего отправлять?

Логичным ходом будет отправлять с сервера "1", все ОК. Если 1 не пришло клиенту, значит сервер недоступен. Но можно ли сделать по другому? Я не хочу ничего отправлять клиенту.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Логичным ходом будет отправлять с сервера "1", все ОК. Если 1 не
>   пришло клиенту, значит сервер недоступен. Но можно ли сделать по
>   другому? Я не хочу ничего отправлять клиенту.

Если сервер упал, то отсутствие ответа и будет ответом в приложении. Установите время в течении которого ждете ответ от сервера и обрабатывайте по прошествии.

Зачем ограничивать пользователя упавшим сервером. Сохраните сообщения пользователя внутри приложения и когда "все наладится" отправляйте на сервер.

> Т.е. я правильно понимаю. Что я не могу никак обойтись без ответа от
>   сервера? В любом случае, мой сервер(смартфон) должен сказать клиенту,
>   что я работаю, либо ничего не сказать, ибо упал. И тогда клиент
>   переподключится.

Отсутсвие ответа от сервера - вы определяете сами, в приложении клиента, сервер ведь упал, время нужного ответа истекло.

Вы продумываете заранее, как поведет себя приложение клиента. Нет ответа в приложении клиента? - "Извините, уже занимаемся вопросом, скоро все будет хорошо".

К чему переподключится клиент? К другому серверу? Все в ваших руках.

Comment: Т.е. я правильно понимаю. Что я не могу никак обойтись без ответа от сервера? В любом случае, мой сервер(смартфон) должен сказать клиенту, что я работаю, либо ничего не сказать, ибо упал. И тогда клиент переподключится.

Comment: А клиент разве не самооповеститься что сервер недоступен при попытке послать на него (писать в закрывшийся сокет)?